# I can't upload my my folders and files to my repository on GitHub

Tags: github

How to upload my folders and files to my repository on GitHub?

I used the following requests:

```sh
git remote add origin
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

But it's not helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have added/committed your code first:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repository
git switch main
git add .
git config --global user.name <your-GitHub-Username>
git config --global user.email <your-GitHub-User-Email>
git commit -m "First commit"
git push -u origin main
```